# switch off resposive css for yii for a module

Tags: yii

hi i'm running a site on YII. which has two module user and admin.
but my config file has bootstrap pre load including responsive css. I want responsive feature for user module only.
i don't want responsive CSS to load in my admin module. is there any way i can unload it only for admin module by doing something on admin layout file?

i have tried

```
$responsiveCss = false
```

but it turns off responsive feature for the whole site.
i want it only for admin module.

thanks

Comment: you can use difrent layout in your controler before render.. $this->layout = 'admin'; $this->render('file');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this on protected/config/main.php,

```
'components' => array(
        'bootstrap' => array(
            'class' => 'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
            'responsiveCss' => !(isset(Yii::app()->controller->module->id) and (Yii::app()->controller->module->id == 'admin' )),
        ),
   ---
),
```

It will make responsive css to all other expert 'admin' module.

Comment: Or, make proper change to address you specific need.

Comment: where i should put it.
main config file or the module layout file?
Thanks

Comment: yes, on main config file like above. I think, you can do job get done now.